# React JS. this.props.children impacts minimize main thread work parameter in the lighthouse audit

Tags: reactjs, lighthouse

I am doing performance testing on the react website. We are using lighthouse extension. I have noticed that `this.props.children` impacts almost 50 points in `minimize main-thread work` parameter. Is it possible to load `this.props.children` effectively without blocking the main thread ? I have attached a screenshot where I removed `this.props.children` and the score improved a lot.

[image]

Comment: that basically means that it took long time to process the code. So may be your trying to render lot of components or doing lot of work in those childrens

Comment: `this.props.children` is *just* an object. It's what your code is doing with *that* prop that affects performance.